# How to Migrate from echoBot to Virtual Assistant?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to migrate the MyBot that I created and run in echoBot to VirtualAssistant.
But there was one problem at the beginning.
There is no "accessor".
I was able to store user information and conversations via an accessor.

How can I store dynamic information without using accessors?

Below is the code I used.

```
var someQuery = await _accessors.SomeQuery.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, ()=> new SomeQuery(), cancellationToken);
```

With the stored query information, I was able to use the query variables at will.

I wonder what the virtual assistant can do to replace this.

Comment: I found a solution. Now I know I have an IStatePropertyAccessor. I was too hasty. I thought the Accessor had disappeared because there was no Accessor class.

Comment: Would you like to post your solution as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: I will do so if it is good.

Comment: Please go ahead and post your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Now I know I have an IStatePropertyAccessor. I was too hasty. I thought the Accessor had disappeared because there was no Accessor class.